# Delete image from Clodinary using axios delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, cloudinary

I am uploading an Image on cloudinary using axios post request and I also want to delete images using axios delete  but I couldn't find any api url or any code that can help me to send delete request to cloudnary using axios delete.

**Using This code to upload image on Cloudinary**

```
let imageFile = this.props.img
        var formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', imageFile)
        formData.append('upload_preset', Routes.CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
        await axios.post(Routes.CLOUDINARY_API, formData)
          .then(function (res) {
            imageURL = res.data.secure_url
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("err", err)
          })
```

Comment: Can you send the code please, the answer is not precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can upload to Cloudinary through the client-side, you cannot delete resources for security reasons. If you would like to delete the resource then `signature` also needs to be passed as a param.

It is recommended to [generate signature](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/signatures#:~:targetText=To%20generate%20the%20signature%2C%20append,or%20SHA%2D256)%20function.&targetText=By%20default%2C%20SHA%2D1%20digest,and%20verify%20all%20Cloudinary%20signatures.) server-side as that requires you to expose your account's API secret.

Comment: How ? i couldn't understand from the link. Is there any example

Comment: Is there any javascript example

Answer (score 0):

To delete an Image from cloudinary using axios post, first you have to create a signature. [Click here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures) to see the documentation to create the signature. Also you will need an library to hash your string to hash1 format. In this example I have used "crypto-hash" library.

In addition to that you will need other parameters such as **public_id**, **api_key** and a **timestamp**.

****Note** - Your **API_Key** and **API-Secret** can be found in your cloudinary account dashboard. After getting all required data, then you can use below code to send the API request. **Public_id** is an unique id to clearly identify the image we need to delete from cloudinary media library.

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime()
const string = `public_id=${<Add public_id>}&timestamp=${timestamp}<add your api secret>`
const signature = await sha1(string)
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append("public_id",<public_id>)
formData.append("signature",signature)
formData.append("api_key",<your api_key>)
formData.append("timestamp",timestamp)
const res = await ax.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<your cloud name>/image/destroy", formData)
```

Comment: I have done all things like you said, but I got this error on response : 401 (Unauthorized). I send this request from nextjs